# Override collection column name

Tags: csvhelper

I have a very simple class I want to write to a CSV.  It contains, for example a "List".  I have the mapping working, and if I add a map statement to provide the name of an index (e.g. 'Index(2, 5).Name("The List ")') it works.  However, the column names come out "The List 1,The List 2,The List 3,The List 4".

I saw an old post saying it was not possible to override these names.  Is that still true?  I've tried playing around with ".Convert" with no success.  I've seen references to examples in the documentation that I haven't been able to find.

At the end of the day, all I want is a map that will take a class like this:

```
    public class SimpleListClass
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<int> TheCollection { get; set; }
    }
```

and let me override the column names of "TheCollection".

Any/all help much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: What do you want the column names to look like?

Comment: In my case, which is relatively simple, I just want, for example, "Pressure 1 (kPa), Pressure 2 (kPa)", etc.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to override the names in the way that you want.  The only way I know to make it work is to manually write out the header.

```cs
void Main()
{
    var records = new List<SimpleListClass>
    {
        new SimpleListClass { Id = 1, Name = "one", TheCollection = new List<int>{1,2,3,4} },
    };
    
    var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    {
        HasHeaderRecord = false
    };

    //using (var writer = new StreamWriter("path\\to\\file.csv"))
    using (var csv = new CsvWriter(Console.Out, config))
    {
        csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<SimpleLIstClassMap>();
        
        csv.WriteField("Id");
        csv.WriteField("Name");
        
        for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
        {
            csv.WriteField($"Pressure {i} (kPa)");
        }
        
        csv.NextRecord();
        
        csv.WriteRecords(records);
    }
}

public class SimpleListClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<int> TheCollection { get; set; }
}

public class SimpleLIstClassMap : ClassMap<SimpleListClass>
{
    public SimpleLIstClassMap()
    {
        Map(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Name);
        Map(x => x.TheCollection).Index(2, 5);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's how I ended up doing it.